# MySql database structure for : Search based on single column and different value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I need to create a database but I'm not getting the correct logic.

It's like a story but I don't have any other way to explain it.

The scene is:
There are three entities; `City`, `Books` and `Library`.

I have to perform a task in which I will get `CityId` and Array of `BookIds` as input and I have to throw the `LibraryNames` based on following criteria:

1. The `Library` should be in the given `City`.
2. The `Library` should have all the books.

I have two input types
First for `City` (It will Provide me a single `CityName` or `CityId`)
and
Second is for `Books` (It will provide an array which consists of multiple `BookIds` or multiple `BookNames`).

If it is hard to understand then please discuss with me I will try to clear the concept.

It is a serious concern of me.

Comment: I don't really understand this, please clarify: Do you have the `CityId` and an array of `BookIds`, and you want to find the `LibraryId`, or the other way around?

Comment: Actually I am not able to decide how to design the database to perform this task. If i will say that I am having CityId and Array of BookIds then it symbolizes that I have created City Master table with Fields (CityId and CityName) And Books Master table with fields (BookId and BookName).

Comment: I have just a story that what i have to do...nothing else....I have created some logics but after a long thinking on it, It fails on some criteria Attaching the Snapshot of that rough Logic. Please wait

Comment: I think you should first design a database and than based on that database try to solve your task

Comment: That is the only problem that, on what concept the database should be designed

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You should have 3 tables (City, Books and Library). We don't really have arrays in sql server. Maybe you are wanting to use a table valued parameter? This article is probably a good place for you to get started. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hm from my point of view you have three table City, Library and Books, start there, create them, column think about the column they should have. Then see in which relation are this table, and create that relationship. One city can have many libraries (one library can be only in one city).

Comment: Yes One city can have multiple libraries but one library can be only in one city as well one library can have multiple books but but a sigle book can be in multiple libraries

Comment: Please think if you have the same condition: That you have to design a database for the following task, On your website user will select City and Books and clicked submit and the result page have to show all the libraries which in the selected city and have all the books which user has been selected. Then what will be your database structure, that is what i want to know

Comment: OK that's great place to start (and that's completely logic) so between tables library and book you have many to many relationship so you need fourth table called book_library or something like that. look online about many to many relationship if you need to. When you create good design for your database and fallow normalization in that process then your task will be peace of cake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
create table City
    (
     Id int,
     Name varchar(50)
    );

    insert into City (Id, Name) 
    VALUES 
    (1, 'Toronto'), 
    (2, 'Chicago')

    create table Libraries(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(50),
    CityId int
    );

    insert into Libraries (Id, Name, CityId) 
    VALUES 
    (1, 'Toronto Library 1', 1),
    (2, 'Toronto Library 2', 1),
    (3, 'Chicago Library 1', 2),
    (4, 'Chicago Library 2', 2)

    create table Books(
    Id int,
    Isbn varchar(12),
    LibraryId int
    );

    insert into Books (Id, Isbn, LibraryId) 
    Values
    (1, '1234567891', 1),
    (2, '13344555', 1),
    (3, 'x123sada', 1),
    (4, 'xasdsadas', 2),
    (5, 'axxzksda', 2)

    select DISTINCT b.Name 
    from Books a
    inner join Libraries b
    on a.LibraryId = b.Id
    where Isbn in ('1234567891', '13344555')
    and b.CityId = 1
```

Edit:
or 4NF:

```
create table City
(
 Id int,
 Name varchar(50)
);

insert into City (Id, Name) 
VALUES 
(1, 'Toronto'), 
(2, 'Chicago')

create table Libraries(
Id int,
Name varchar(50),
CityId int
);

insert into Libraries (Id, Name, CityId) 
VALUES 
(1, 'Toronto Library 1', 1),
(2, 'Toronto Library 2', 1),
(3, 'Chicago Library 1', 2),
(4, 'Chicago Library 2', 2)

create table Books(
Id int,
Isbn varchar(12),
);

insert into Books (Id, Isbn) 
Values
(1, '1234567891'),
(2, '13344555'),
(3, 'x123sada'),
(4, 'xasdsadas'),
(5, 'axxzksda')

create table LibraryBooks
(
LibraryId int,
BookId int
);

insert into LibraryBooks (LibraryId, BookId)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(3, 1),
(2, 4),
(5, 2)

select DISTINCT c.Name
from Books a
inner join LibraryBooks b
on a.Id = b.BookId
inner join Libraries c on
c.Id = b.LibraryId
where Isbn in ('1234567891', '13344555')
and c.CityId = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this, Still I dont kow It will work or not but it seems that it may be the solution of my question, Going to try it and reply back

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil this solution will probably work but relation between tables book and libraries should be many to many. In case like this if there is one book in multiple libraries you'll have multiple entries in book table for each library for the same book... Example if the book with isbn 444445 is in 3 library then you'll have three entries like id, 5, isbn 444445 libraryId 1, next row id 6, isbn 444445, LibraryId 2, next row id 7, isbn 444445, LibraryId 4 etc... that's not exactly by the rules of normalization...

Comment: @Aleksandar Miladinovic Yes you are correct but there is no right or wrong answer because it really depends on what you are doing. If you are building a content management system where you are going to give the ability to create, delete, and modify books then yes 4NF is the best solution. If you are working with lots of data and want fast performance then this is the better approach because it does not need to inner join another table. If you are bulk inserting from csv or external source then this would be the better approach. It really depends..

Comment: I agree but I think this is some kind of homework where they need to design a database and fallow all rules of normalization bla bla bla... So probably this is the first database they will develop and it's good to be familiar with all concept and how all relations work etc...

Comment: Yes then you are right 100%. See edit

Comment: @MIKE I tried it and it is giving me the desired dataset, I am having the same concern that the books table will have multiple no. of rows which contain the duplicate data (i.e ISBN), I have to perform CRUD operation also. If you have some more Idea then please discuss, I guess I should wait for some more time or find some more Logics, If i will find then definitely will post it here otherwise will use your logic

Comment: That's it :) don't have anything to add @AlokKumarNikhil Here is your answer. Hope you'll wont just rewrite it and bring it to school... :) ask everything you don't understand. And use google A LOT

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic Am I wrong if I asked a solution which i am not able to find.

Comment: p.s. You still have to add primary key and foreign key constraints to get perfect marks

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil of course not :) if I thought you're wrong I wouldn't put any effort to help you with my comments. Just saying that if you don't understand any part of this relationship between table or query MIKE wrote for you ask again, and again and again till you get clear with that.

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic @ MIKE  @ Mads Marquart for helping me, Thank you so much

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic Yes I agree with you

Comment: Hey, I think the question heading is not appropriate, Is there any suggesion ? So that this post can help sombody else

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil you're welcome... don't know about heading, but I have one more little suggestion for you. There is up vote button (on top every answer and question) 'this answer is useful' button so when someone like MIKE help you with your problem it's polite to mark his answer as useful at least and to accept his answer if it's completely solve your problem. It's not big deal for you but he will collect some points which will bring him some status in stock community and some benefits.

Comment: @ Aleksandar Miladinovic  @ MIKE  I am totally agree with you, and definitely I will do it, I can understand it, But in the meanwhile i was busy in writing my answer, sorry for that, Please review my answer and give me the appropriate reason, Why I should not use that, one of the reason which I came across is, It is lengthy to perform CRUD Operation.  Please give me your Valuable sugessions.

Comment: An please up vote the question if you find it beneficial for somebody else

Answer (score 0):

You could structure it like this: (Three tables)

```
City:
Id, Name
```

`Id` = unique number

```
Library:
Id, Name, LiesInCity
```

`Id` = unique number
`LiesInCity` = The city `Id` the library lies in.

```
Book:
Id, Name, LiesInLibrary
```

`Id` = number
`LiesInLibrary` = The library `Id` the book is in.

Then you would `SELECT` the book list you had, and check if they are all in that `Library`. (You would also check if the `Library` is in the right `City`)

Note: You would need to have multiple `Book` entries if a book is in multiple `Library`'s

Comment: there is a little problem library - book relation should be many to many (book with the same name can be in multiple libraries and multiple libraries can have the book with same name) so you can solve that with the fourth table... which is in practice much better solution then to have multiple book entries...

Comment: @ Aleksandar Miladinovic Yes you are right, So did you got any logic to create such databse if yes, then please share with me.

Comment: @AlokKumarNikhil I hope that you'll done whole job and that I will just make suggestion :) but if you want I will write the answer... I thought that the first way is better for learning and understanding of problem :)