# MySql:pricelist table for single_item-multiple_price depending upon different suppliers with Effective_From_Date and Effective_Till_Date

Tags: mysql

Is there any best way to design pricelist Table(MySql) for items having multiple price(depending upon each individual supplier) with Price_Effective_Date and Price_Effective_Till?

My database is having following table :

1. m_item

Table fields :

`item_id            int(255)
item_category_id    int(255)
item_name           varchar(255)
item_description    longtext`

2. m_supplier

Table fields :

`supplier_id      int(255)
 supplier_name    varchar(25)`

3. tbl_supplier_item_binding

Table fields :

`tbl_supplier_item_binding_id   int(255)
supplier_id                     int(255)
item_id                         int(255)`

My approach to do this:

4. tbl_item_pricelist

Table fields :

`price_list_id  int(255)
supplier_item_binding_id    int(255)
item_price  int(10) (Only to show on web)
item_discounted_price   int(10)
supplier_actual_price   int(10)
price_effective_date        (TIMESTAMP)
price_effective_till        (TIMESTAMP)`.

Is it good way to do this, I am not confident on my approach.
Needed suggestion.

Comment: What is the actual purpose of your table # **3**?

Comment: Hello, **Tbl#3** is used to bind item and supplier because each item can be associated to multiple supplier. I need to define price list of an Item. 1. The price of the same item is different for each supplier (In simple words, Each item is associated with multiple suppliers and every supplier is having his own rate). 2. Price list is having 3 type of price (a) item_price (It is used only to show the price on website), (b) item_discounted_price (Payable price for customers), (c) supplier_actual_price (Given by supplier to web owner, which will be less than item_price and item_discounted_price)

Comment: Why couldn't you just add `supplier_id` and `item_id` into your Price List?  What advantage a separate "binding" table gives you?  From what I see you have a simple many-to-many situation that is usually solved with 3 tables.

Comment: Actually I have to perform an action where I have to get all the item associated with any random supplier. Please visit this link if i am not able to make it understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575979/mysql-database-structure-for-search-based-on-single-column-and-different-value

Comment: @PM77-1Are you ther?

Comment: I am waiting for some positive conversation.

Comment: I am waiting for some positive conversation.